# This code won't work// How to get the div to slide in-line with other divs on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, division

I am aware there are discussions similar and I have read them, analysed them and tried them in my code. The code below is what I currently have, trust me, I have spent all day exhausting all methods to prevent me from asking here but I give up! This is by far the most frustrating goal.

I would like to have a header with a little bar that slides across above each menu item on hover over. A perfect example of what I would like is located here at http://www.wix.com/ . Please visit and move your mouse over the navigation bar and you'll understand instatly what I am trying to achieve.

Here is my current code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
div {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#red {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#blue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
    height:100px;
    width:170px;
}
#slider{
    background-color:#6FF;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="slider"></div><br />
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="blue" onmouseover="javascript:movetoblue()" onmouseout="javascript:exitblue()"></div>
        <div id="yellow" onmouseover="javascript:movetoyellow()" onmouseout="javascript:exityellow()"></div>
        <div id="green" onmouseover="javascript:movetogreen()" onmouseout="javascript:exitgreen()"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById( 'slider' );

function movetoblue(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '100px', width: '160px'}, "slow");
}
function exitblue(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '7px', width: '200px'}, "slow");
}
function movetoyellow(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '100px', width: '160px'}, "slow");
}
function exityellow(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '7px', width: '200px'}, "slow");
}
function movetogreen(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '100px', width: '160px'}, "slow");
}
function exitgreen(){
        var slider = $("#slider");  
        slider.animate({left: '7px', width: '200px'}, "slow");
}
</script>
```

I know much is probably wrong with it. Sigh. But any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

PS: I would like this to work on Chrome, IE, Safari and Firefox, but I'm mainly concerned about Chrome, IE, Safari. Thanks again!

Comment: Here's the code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cf3v89g/
Depending on your browser (might be slightly different but whatever...), you should be able to right click on an element and  `inspect element` (the Wix header) and get an idea of how they are doing it.

Comment: I did @LukeAdams look at the inspect element and I couldn't access the slider properties or anytihng

Comment: Sorry for not really helping much, i got busy just as I posted my comment. @Hossein's answer looks perfect ;)
I dug into how they did it, and he implemented it the same way.

Comment: @LukeAdams Please look at this and see if you can help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197291/unanswered-positioning-this-div-is-a-nightmare-please-assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are using jQuery but in a very wrong way. I've created a JSFiddle for you. take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/Lhcaeboz/2/)

**Update 1:**

Edited The Code For Better Performance By Adding:

```
$("#slider").stop()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(".item:first").position().left + "px",
      "width": $(".item:first").width() + "px"
    }, 0);
  
  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop()
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
      "width": $(this).width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: #E2BE22;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
#green {
  background-color: #008800;
  height: 100px;
  width: 170px;
}
#slider {
  background-color: #6FF;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="red" class="item"></div>
<div id="blue" class="item"></div>
<div id="yellow" class="item"></div>
<div id="green" class="item"></div>
```

**Update 2:**

For Deining The Start Position You Should Replace This Part:

```
$("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(".item:first").position().left + "px",
      "width": $(".item:first").width() + "px"
}, 0);
```

With This:

```
$("#slider").animate({
      "left": $("#TAG_ID").position().left + "px",
      "width": $("#TAG_ID").width() + "px"
}, 0);
```

**NOTE** TAG_ID is your starting div id property

**Update 3:**

In case that user didn't select a tab:

```
$("#slider").delay(3000).animate({
    "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
    "width": $(this).width() + "px"
}, 500);
```

Comment: Can you please help me again @HosseinMaktoobian Please look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197291/unanswered-positioning-this-div-is-a-nightmare-please-assist

Comment: @nobodyshere yeah. let me see