# Positioning this div is a nightmare please assist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, division

[image]

In this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/Lj0x38f2/6/, you can see that this line of code...

```
<div style="float:right; font-size:24px; font-family:'Myriad Pro';">Above</div>
```

causes an issue because it is supposed to be directly above the navigation bar whilst still floating to the right, but instead it pushes the navigation bar out from the right hand side, when the navigation bar should be sitting underneath that div in alignment with the base of the header.

When I say the navigation bar, I am indeed referring to all of the code below...

```
<div style="float:right"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
            <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
                <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
                <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
                <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
                <a href="apps.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Apps</div></div></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please keep in mind that the navigation bar is easily ruined when repositioning the divs.

All the code together is...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container"> <!-- This is the container -->
    <div class="header"> <!-- This is the header -->
        <div style="float:left"> <!-- This is the logo -->
            <img src="images/mattsubishilogowhite.png" height="120px"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size:24px; font-family:'Myriad Pro';">Above</div>
        <div style="float:right; clear:both"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
            <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
                <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
                <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
                <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
                <a href="apps.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Apps</div></div></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body"> <!-- This is the body -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> <!-- This is the footer -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").animate({
    "left": $(".item:first").position().left + "px",
    "width": $(".item:first").width() + "px"
  }, 0);

  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
      "width": $(this).width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".item").on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $('#one').position().left + "px",
      "width": $('#one').width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });
});
</script>
<script>
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
var isAtLeastIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
if(isChrome){
    alert("Your using Chrome, please be aware that using Chrome will reduce some functionality of this website therefore you should use Internet Explorer version 11 or higher.");
}else{
    if(!isAtLeastIE11){
        alert("Your version of Internet Explorer is below 11. It needs to be 11 or higher for some aspects of this website's functionality to work. Please update or use Chrome.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want it on top of the navigation bar, use something like `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.

Comment: 1. Put the full content of your question **in** your question, don't just link to it. You can (and should) create a runnable [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) here on site. 2. PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. 3. Your shouted note at the end is just completely not how you should warn people about that. How about "Before it trips you up, just a head's up that the navigation bar layout is easily messed up by repositioning that div" (ideally with more information about that). Remember, you're **asking** people to spend their time helping you. Be respectful of that.

Comment: put `clear:both` on navigation menu

Comment: `position:fixed` isn't what I am looking for which is clearly outlined in the question. `position:absolute` doesn't produce the desired result. @gcampbell

Comment: which line???????? @Master.Deep

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "directly above the navigation bar whilst still floating to the right"?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Add an image of what the desired result be.

Comment: Ok please give me a moment

Comment: `<div style="float:right; clear:both"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->` change navigation menu div styling to this

Comment: I can't seem to upload an image?

Comment: <div style="float:right; clear:both"> <!-- This is the navigation menu --> This did not fix the issue

Comment: I added an image! Hope that helps!!! @Pugazh

Comment: Please describe your issue in more detail

Comment: I hope the image helps @gcampbell

Comment: I cant get the navigation bar to sit under the div with the text "above" in it

Comment: Please refer to image @Master.Deep

Comment: can you show me an image of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Of course! OMG THANK YOU FOR RETURNING!

Comment: Oops I forgot to tag you @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: Yes I have just uploaded the image for you @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: I hope that helps! Good luck! @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian This JSFiddle shows what I want actually but it sadly doesn't work when put back into the original HTML file. https://jsfiddle.net/MasterDeep/rz0L4559/ Once putting the code back into the HTML file, the navigation bar was actually pushed outside the header but in the JSFiddle, its perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `clear:both` to your navigation div it will come down and you should remove the height of your `.header` to fit the content. so it will just fit the provided image. here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").animate({
    "left": $(".item:first").position().left + "px",
    "width": $(".item:first").width() + "px"
  }, 0);

  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
      "width": $(this).width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".item").on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $('#one').position().left + "px",
      "width": $('#one').width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
body{ /* Applies to the <body> tag */
 margin:0px; /* Sets the margin on all sides to 0px */
}
.container{ /* The container class */
 width:100%; /* This sets the width */
 height:100%; /* This sets the height */
 background-color:black; /* Sets the background colour */
}
.header{ /* The header class */
 width:100%;
 background-color:#323232;
 color:white; /* The sets the colour of the font */
}
.body{
 width:100%;
 height:495px;
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
}
.footer{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#323232;
 color:white;
}
div{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four{
    background-color:#323232;
    height:96px;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:25px;
 font-family:"Myriad Pro";
}
#slider{
    background-color:#ed1c24;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.inside{
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;
 padding-top:7px;
 pointer-events:none;
 margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <!-- This is the container -->
 <div class="header"> <!-- This is the header -->
     <div style="float:left"> <!-- This is the logo -->
         <img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png" height="100px">
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size:24px; font-family:'Myriad Pro';">Above</div>
        <div style="float:right; clear:right"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
         <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
             <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
             <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
       <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
       <a href="apps.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Apps</div></div></a>
       <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body"> <!-- This is the body -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer"> <!-- This is the footer -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just testing it now @hosseinmaktoobian

Comment: when I put my logo back into that line it ruined it, as it was working before I put the image back into the div

Comment: i will update the snippet with an image for the logo

Comment: Thank you!!! :D @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: Your Welcome. Take A Look At This Now

Comment: what line did you change?

Comment: why do I keep forgetting to tag you @hosseinmaktoobian

Comment: @nobodyshere this `<div style="float:right; clear:both"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->` and this `.header{ /* The header class */`(removed the height from here)

Comment: so the height class should look like this? .header{ /* The header class */
 width:100%;
 background-color:#323232;
 color:white; /* The sets the colour of the font */
}

Comment: and the other one looks like this <div style="float:right; clear:both"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->

Comment: I can't see any differences and yet it still isn't working? @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: I have copied the exact code I have in the original question. What is different too yours? There's no height in the header class and the div has clear:both

Comment: so that should work

Comment: I am so confused *cries and laughs simultaenously* if you can't see any issue with my code, then why is it not working? Would you like me too upload a picture of the result of the code in the original Question. @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: @nobodyshere yes. upload the result or upload your original code that does not work so i can fix it

Comment: Ok. I have uploaded my current code and logo as well. @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: @nobodyshere oh you want the logo to be in front of the navigation?

Comment: @nobodyshere just change `clear:both` to `clear:right`

Comment: I DON'T KNOW HOW YOU DO IT! YOU'RE A GENIUS! IT WORKED! OMG! THANK YOU SO MUCH, I'D GIVE YOU ALL MY REPUTATION POINTS IF I COULD!!! I WILL ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER OF COURSE! AGAIN, OMG, YOU'RE A GENIUS THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! @HosseinMaktoobian

Comment: @nobodyshere anytime ;-)

Comment: Hi @HosseinMaktoobian , I was just wondering what to do in regards to a new issue that has become apparent to me. I made my website 100% in width which is fine, but the elements and the margins are all thrown off when I view the website on a desktop with a larger screen and resolution. What can I do to fix this. The laptop I create the website on is extremely small so all margins and stuff look perfect on here, except for horizontal alignment, as margin:auto don't work for me so I just made a guess, and vertical alignment is a night mare so I just add line breaks but the bigger the screen...

Comment: ...the worse the problem. For some reason margin:auto for example don't work. So I think I ended up using percentages which were ruined when viewing my site on a bigger desktop. I don't how to make my site display everything in the same ratio, regardless of screen size or resolution so that margins aren't effected??? I hope I explained this well enough, I tried too but I am not good explaining things sometimes. I have tried to read about it online and most of the options made no sense to me??

Comment: @nobodyshere I think you need to read about flexible and resposive web design in css. this key words will help you up