# Get div innetText by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new at Javascript.
I have the following table:

```
  <table id='master_tbl'>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="master_hr'>
       <td class="myclass">
          <table>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <td>
                           <span class="myclass2>
                                  <div class="myclass3">MyText</div>
                            </span>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

How can i get the "MyText" string?
Note: I cannot add any id attribute to the html text.

Comment: use the class `.myclass3` and use `textContent` not `innerText` as it's [way faster](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
var m = document.getElementById("master_hr").getElementsByClassName("myclass3")[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var m= document.getElementsByClassName('myclass3')[0].innerHTML
```

Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/833j8qoo/1/)

You can also use [**textContent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text

Note there are some unbalanced quotes like `<tr id="master_hr'>` & `<span class="myclass2>`

Comment: I second using `textContent` over `innerText`. It's [way faster](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass3')[0].innerText
```

Comment: Use `textContent` not `innerText`. It's [way faster](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

Answer (score 0):

In the  tags put...

```
var mytext = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass3')[0].innerText;
alert(mytext);
```

Comment: `<div>` elements do not have `value` properties

Comment: Because I personally prefer that method

Comment: @nobodyshere — You can't. `value` doesn't work and the question explicitly forbids adding an `id`.

Comment: @nobodyshere lol ... still, `value` isn't a valid property of a div element.

Comment: No one has been able to help me with my question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197291/unanswered-positioning-this-div-is-a-nightmare-please-assist?noredirect=1#comment63819571_38197291

Comment: @evolutionxbox No one has been able to help therefore... I am trying to be nice and help others.... My question has been available for a long time. No one can see more question anymore :(

Comment: @nobodyshere - huh? I'm not questioning how nice you are... (psst, use textContent rather than innerText)

Comment: I know :) @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0):

You can also use querySelector if you want only the first match or else you can use querySelectorAll().

Using querySelector :

```
document.querySelector(".myclass3").innerHTML
```

Using querySelectorAll :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myclass3")[0].innerHTML
```